# Avoid creation of _$folder$ keys in S3 with hadoop (EMR)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am using an EMR Activity in AWS data pipeline. This EMR Activity is running a hive script in EMR Cluster. It takes dynamo DB as input and stores data in S3.

This is the EMR step used in EMR Activity

```
s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script,--run-hive-script,--hive-versions,latest,--args,-f,s3://my-s3-bucket/hive/my_hive_script.q,-d,DYNAMODB_INPUT_TABLE1=MyTable,-d,S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET=#{output.directoryPath}
```

where

out.direcoryPath is :

```
s3://my-s3-bucket/output/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,"YYYY-MM-dd")}
```

So this creates one folder and one file in S3. (technically speaking it creates two keys `2017-03-18/<some_random_number>` and `2017-03-18_$folder$`)

```
2017-03-18
2017-03-18_$folder$
```

How to avoid creation of these extra empty `_$folder$` files.

EDIT:
I found a solution listed at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10400 but I don't know how to implement it in AWS data pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EMR doesn't seem to provide a way to avoid this.

> Because S3 uses a key-value pair storage system, the Hadoop file system implements directory support in S3 by creating empty files with the "_$folder$" suffix.
>
> You can safely delete any empty files with the `<directoryname>_$folder$` suffix that appear in your S3 buckets. These empty files are created by the Hadoop framework at runtime, but Hadoop is designed to process data even if these empty files are removed.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/

It's in the Hadoop source code, so it could be fixed, but apparently it's not fixed in EMR.

If you are feeling clever, you could create an S3 event notification that matches the _$folder$ suffix, and have it fire off a Lambda function to delete the objects after they're created.

Comment: I found a solution listed at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10400 but I don't know how to implement it in AWS data pipeline.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal I believe you can't, with EMR -- it's a managed service.

Answer (score 18):

use s3a while writing to s3 bucket, it will remove *$folder$*. i have tested this glue. not sure if it will apply in EMR clusters.

Credit:- answered by someone on reddit

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df=spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3://testingbucket/")
df.write.format("parquet").save("s3a://testingbucket/parttest/")
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Tried on glue ETL and it worked as expected. Many thanks!

Comment: Wow...THIS IS THE ANSWER!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This Answer should be the accepted one..

Comment: Thanks, worked for me in EMR Hadoop, while writing to S3.

Comment: Worked great for me on a Glue Development Endpoint. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way in S3 to actually create an empty folder.
S3 is an object store so everything is an object in there.

When Hadoop uses it as a filesystem, it requires to organize those objects so that it appears as a file system tree, so it creates some special objects to mark an object as a directory.

You just store data files, but you can choose to organize those data files into paths, which creates a concept similar to folders for traversing.

Some tools including AWS Management Console mimic folders by interpreting /s in object names. The Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. So does the Bucket Explorer.

If you just don't create a folder, but place files in the path you want - that should work for you.

**You don't have to create a folder before writing files to it in S3 because `/all/path/including/filename` - is a whole key in the S3 storage.**

Comment: *"There's no way in S3 to actually create an empty folder."*  That isn't true. While it's true that folders do not really exist, any object whose key ends with a trailing slash is interpreted by the console as a folder.  Unfortunately, Hadoop uses this goofy `_$folder$` construct, entirely unnecessarily, since it could just use `/` -- which is what happens when you "create a folder" in the console.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It's true about S3, it has only buckets and keys. But some tools can mimic folders by interpreting /s in object names. The Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. So does the Bucket Explorer. See here: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-create-a-folder.html

Comment: Hadoop s3n client uses the $folder$ marker for historical reasons; I think originally you couldn't use "/". The newer S3a Client uses "/"; it ignores $folder$ files in listings. Amazon EMR's S3 connector is their own code, it appears to still use $folder$. Their decision.

Comment: @SteveLoughran Are there any links detailing the switch from "_$folder$" to "/" ?

Comment: Not AFAIK, you could look through the Hadoop NativeS3FileSystem code history

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using s3:// use s3a:// will solve your issue

This happens because of the S3 path you use during writing.

s3:// vs s3a://

s3:// will make the folder s3a:// will not

The prefixes `s3://` and `s3a://` are both used to specify the protocol for accessing data stored in Amazon S3 within Apache Spark.

1. `s3://`: This prefix is used to specify the S3 protocol for accessing data in Spark. It is the default protocol used by Spark and provides basic functionality for reading and writing data from and to S3. When using `s3://`, Spark uses the Hadoop S3A connector to interact with S3.
2. `s3a://`: This prefix is also used to specify the S3 protocol for accessing data in Spark. It is an alternative protocol that provides additional features and optimizations compared to `s3://`. When using `s3a://`, Spark uses the Hadoop S3A connector, which is an improved version of the S3 connector.

In general, it is recommended to use `s3a://` instead of `s3://` when working with Spark and S3, as `s3a://` offers better performance and reliability. However, the specific choice between `s3://` and `s3a://` may depend on your specific use case and requirements.

For example, to specify the input or output path for reading or writing data to S3 using `s3://`, you can use the following syntax:

```py
inputPath = "s3://your-bucket/your-input-path"
outputPath = "s3://your-bucket/your-output-path"
```

Similarly, to use `s3a://`, you can replace `s3://` with `s3a://` in the path:

```py
inputPath = "s3a://your-bucket/your-input-path"
outputPath = "s3a://your-bucket/your-output-path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below script in EMR bootstrap action to solve this issue. Patch provided by AWS

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: This script replaces the s3-dist-cp RPM on EMR versions 4.6.0+ with s3-dist-cp-2.2.0.
# This is intended to remove the _$folder$ markers when creating the destination prefixes in S3.

set -ex

RPM=bootstrap-actions/s3-dist-cp-2.2.0/s3-dist-cp-2.2.0-1.amzn1.noarch.rpm

LOCAL_DIR=/var/aws/emr/packages/bigtop/s3-dist-cp/noarch

# Get the region from metadata
REGION=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/ 2>/dev/null | head -c -1)

# Choose correct bucket for region
if [ $REGION = "us-east-1" ]
then
    BUCKET=awssupportdatasvcs.com
else
    BUCKET=$REGION.awssupportdatasvcs.com
fi

# Download new RPM
sudo rm $LOCAL_DIR/s3-dist-cp*.rpm
aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$RPM /tmp/
sudo cp /tmp/s3-dist-cp-2.2.0-1.amzn1.noarch.rpm $LOCAL_DIR/

echo Rebuilding Repo
sudo yum install -y createrepo
sudo createrepo --update -o /var/aws/emr/packages/bigtop /var/aws/emr/packages/bigtop
sudo yum clean all
```