# How to configure Spark / Glue to avoid creation of empty $_folder_$ after Glue job successful execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

I have a simple glue etl job which is triggered by Glue workflow. It drop duplicates data from a crawler table and writes back the result into a S3 bucket. The job is completed successfully . However the empty folders that spark generates "$*folder*$" remain in s3. It does not look nice in the hierarchy and causes confusion. Is there any way to configure spark or glue context to hide/remove these folders after successful completion of the job?

[image]

---------------------S3 image ---------------------
[image]

Comment: According to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/), it's caused by Hadoop. I guess you can use a lambda function to delete `$folder$` on the S3 object creation event.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AchyutVyas . I would prefer to avoid manual deletion ... The strange thing is that those $folder$ s are not always created... I suspect that when I trigger the glue job manually it, it does not create the folder but when I use the workflow , those folders are created. Not sure though! Have to test again. Will update the question shortly...

Comment: Hey, @Lina using lambda to delete `$folder$` is not manual deletion. will you please also test that after deleting `$folder$` is it also gets created using the same method of job trigger?

Comment: Thank @AchyutVyas. By saying manual I mean doing extra actions to hide/delete the folder.I would prefer to configure the spark in a way that it will not generate the folder at all. I was testing this locally and found an interesting thing.If I use the [AWS glue lib] (https://learning.tusharsarde.com/2019/11/run-aws-glue-job-in-pycharm-community-edition.html) to run glue jobs locally,it does not create $folder$ in the cloud s3 bucket. I tried to use the same glue version, disable bookmark in the cloud job but the cloud job creates those folders.still testing to see what the difference is

Comment: @AchyutVyas found the answer. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok finally after few days of testing I found the solution. Before pasting the code let me summarize what I have found ...

- Those $folder$ are created via Hadoop .Apache Hadoop creates these files when to create a folder in an S3 bucket. [Source1](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/)
  They are actually directory markers as path + /. [Source 2](https://www.edureka.co/community/920/difference-between-s3n-s3a-and-s3#:%7E:text=s3%20is%20a%20block%2Dbased,is%20the%20successor%20to%20s3n.)
- To change the behavior , you need to change the Hadoop S3 write configuration in Spark context. Read [this](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/cloud-filesystem/aws-filesystem.html) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/testing-glue-pyspark-jobs-4b544d62106e) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876195/avoid-creation-of-folder-keys-in-s3-with-hadoop-emr#:%7E:text=Because%20S3%20uses%20a%20key,%22_%24folder%24%22%20suffix.&text=These%20empty%20files%20are%20created,these%20empty%20files%20are%20removed.)
- Read about S3 , S3a and S3n [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/53425/what-is-the-difference-between-s3n-s3a-and-s3) and [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/35959/what-is-the-difference-between-using-s3a-s3n-and-s.html)
- Thanks to @stevel 's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125955/dynamically-folder-creation-in-s3-bucket-from-pyspark-job)

Now the solution is to set the following configuration in Spark context Hadoop.

```
sc = SparkContext()
hadoop_conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
```

To avoid creation of SUCCESS files you need to set the following configuration as well :
`hadoop_conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")`

Make sure you use the S3 URI for writing to s3 bucket. ex:

```
myDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet('s3://XXX/YY',partitionBy['DDD'])
```

Comment: Spot on.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! This is also great to set if you're looking to give your glue jobs least privilege roles - ie access to a particular path in s3 rather than full bucket access! I was getting permission denied and it was all to do with trying to write these _$folder$ files!